# Enabling Just-In-Tme Debugger without admin rights

Tags: delphi, debugging

How to enable Just-In-Time debugger for Delphi 6 without admin rights?

Comment: Is this a Delphi question or a Windows question? Ie, are you saying you don't know how to get a particular app to launch as the JIT Debugger in some version of Windows? I mean ... Delphi itself does not seem to be the issue here. If JIT Debugging requires the app to run in Admin mode, what does that have to do with Delphi?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Modifying these settings requires administrator rights. That is because the settings live in the `HKLM` hive of the registry.

Comment: IN HKLM hive value is set correctly, but on launch Delphi 6 appears dialog window with question about debugger setting.

Comment: That's a different issue. You asked how to modify JIT debugger settings without admin rights.

Comment: I asked how to enable JIT debugger. Despite the fact that the registry key is set correctly, without admin rights debugger does not works.

Comment: I guess the reg key is not set correctly. But you asked how to do this without admin rights. You cannot.